# how can i collapse my content when i click button "Hủy"

Tags: reactjs, antd

Hi can someone help me close the content when i click button Huy in these code

```
<Collapse.Panel header="Username" key="username">
              <Form
                labelAlign="right"
                labelCol={{ offset: 6 }}
                onFinish={onFinishUsername}
                onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
              >
                <Form.Item
                  label="Username"
                  name="username"
                  rules={[{ required: true }, { warningOnly: true }]}
                >
                  <Input />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ offset: 6 }}>
                  <Row justify="end">
                    <Col pull={1}>
                      <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                        Lưu
                      </Button>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                      <Button>Huỷ</Button>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </Form.Item>
              </Form>
            </Collapse.Panel>
```

Example:
Before I click button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k84Bg.png)

and after click
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbyef.png)

Comment: which UI component you use?

Comment: @yonghu I'm using ant design

Comment: maybe can help you https://blog.logrocket.com/create-collapsible-react-components-react-collapsed/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In antd design, activeKey of the Collapse component is the property which control which panel to spread out, you can control the property in the callback of the click:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import { Collapse, Form, Input, Row, Col, Button } from "antd";


const onFinishUsername = () => {};
const onFinishFailed = () => {};

const App: React.FC = () => {

  const defaultActivePanel = ["username"];
  const [activedPanel, setActivedPanel] = useState(defaultActivePanel);
  const clickButton = () => {
    console.log("clickButton");
    setActivedPanel([]);
  };
  const onChange = (key: string[]) => {
    setActivedPanel(key);
  };
  return (
    <Collapse
      defaultActiveKey={activedPanel}
      activeKey={activedPanel}
      onChange={onChange}
    >
      <Collapse.Panel header="Username" key="username">
        <Form
          labelAlign="right"
          labelCol={{ offset: 6 }}
          onFinish={onFinishUsername}
          onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
        >
          <Form.Item
            label="Username"
            name="username"
            rules={[{ required: true }, { warningOnly: true }]}
          >
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ offset: 6 }}>
            <Row justify="end">
              <Col pull={1}>
                <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                  Lưu
                </Button>
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Button onClick={clickButton}>Huỷ</Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </Collapse.Panel>
    </Collapse>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: thank you so much it's close when i click button but when i click collapse Username it's doesn't open form =((

Comment: @namnguyen 
```   
const onChange = (key: string | string[]) => {
    console.log(key);
    setActivedPanel((item)=>item.length?[]:["username"]);
  };
``` 
Use function `setActivedPanel` to control the status of the activedPanel

Comment: @namnguyen If my answer was helpful to you, I would greatly appreciate it if you could consider accepting it. The reputation I earn from providing good answers serves as my motivation to continue doing so.

Comment: So when i have more collapse (eg: username and full-name) i use  const onChange = (key: string | string[]) => { console.log(key); setActivedPanel((item)=>item.length?['full-name']:['username']); to close and open each collapse according to the key right?

Comment: No,use this:```  const onChange = (key: string[]) => {
    // activedPanel.splice()
    setActivedPanel(key);
  };``` [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ans-for-collapse-panel-zj9n9w) is here

Comment: Oh thank you so much - Best wishes for you